# Как сгенерировать UUID с определённым/постоянным суффиксом?

Tags: java, uuid, guid

Возникла задача создания [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) с определённым префиксом. Префикс должен быть вычисляемым на основании определённой строки, т.е. имея одну и ту-же строку UUID должны иметь один и тот-же префикс.
Взяв за основу эту [статью](https://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid) и немного модифицировав код получил следующее решение:

```java
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Random;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        final long _seed = getStringHashAsLong( "ABCDEF");
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            final String _uuid = new UUID( _seed, get64LeastSignificantBitsForVersion1() );
            System.out.println( _uuid );
        }
    }

    static long get64LeastSignificantBitsForVersion1()
    {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final long random63BitLong = random.nextLong() & 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
        return random63BitLong | 0x8000000000000000L;
    }

    static long getStringHashAsLong( String string )
    {
        long h = 1125899906842597L;
        final int len = string.length();
        for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        {
            h = 31 * h + string.charAt( i );
        }
        return h;
    }
}
```

В результате выполнения программы будет выведено следующее:

```
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-8000-1769ede97240
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-8437-7931e0f0f93c
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-bc5f-1456e9bed2d0
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-82b9-6df89aa2b7cb
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-b267-8ee8b7dfbcfb
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-9f35-3f0de384775e
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-af51-9133329f766c
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-9985-31199f0a707e
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-a34f-51e13a61bed1
ed03fffa-de64-4c88-86aa-f267d0ddde7a
```

Простые подсчёты *(16 позиций символов суффикса ^ 16 возможных значений в каждой позиции)* показывают, что возможных вариантов почти 18 с половиной квадриллионов, но насколько вероятна возможность создания одинаковых UUID принимая во внимание тот факт, что префикс "жестко" закреплён?

Comment: Поправил вопрос по просьбам минусующих, чтоб он был сосредоточен на одной проблеме/вопросе.

Comment: Минус не мой, но тогда это уже не GUID UUID - эти форматы стандартизованы, а вы делаете какой-то непонятный гибрид )

Comment: @Kromster в спецификации [указано](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#:~:text=Society%20(2005).%0A%0AAbstract-,This%20specification%20defines%20a%20Uniform%20Resource%20Name%20namespace%20for%0A%20%20%20UUIDs%20(Universally%20Unique%20IDentifier)%2C%20also%20known%20as%20GUIDs%20(Globally%0A%20%20%20Unique%20IDentifier).,-A%20UUID%20is) и то и другое. Я понимаю, что между ними есть разница, но в данном конкретном случае это не имеет значения. Помимо этого конструктор принимает аргументами значения для старших и младших битов, т.е. такое использование подразумевалось.

Comment: Просто не совсем понимаю, зачем укладывать это в GUID, а не просто взять 8 байт хеша определенной строки и 8 байт хэша данных.

Comment: @Kromster значения будут сохраняться в столбец MS SQL с типом uniqueidentifier. Изменять таблицу нельзя. Предполагается генерировать префикс из полного имени класса для дальнейшей фильтрации данных. Может я заморачиваюсь и есть другое решение, но я его пока не вижу.

Comment: "Кроилово ведет к попадалову"

Comment: Очень похоже на создание собственного аналога `Hibernate 6 UUID time-based generator`: https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/#ip-and-timestamp-based-uuid-ietf-rfc-4122-version-1

Answer (score 0):

Для Вашей задачи более всего подойдет еще не принятый стандарт [UUID v8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format#name-uuid-version-8), причем фиксированный префикс будет размещен в поле `custom_a` (48 бит).

Поле `custom_b` (12 бит) можно использовать как часть префикса, если custom_a не достаточно или сгенерировать на основе таймера или заполнить рэндомными значениями.

Поле `custom_c` (62 бит) можно заполнить рэндомными значениями.

Используйте `SecureRandom` для минимизации коллизий.

Comment: Как это выглядит на практике? Можно ли создать сие стандартными средствами Java?